# TextField Cursor initial position

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a javafx `TextField` with an image in the text field to left. When the `TextField` is focused the cursor appears right on the image, I want the cursor to appear next to image.

#### current look

[image: How it appears]

#### desired look

[image: How i need it to be appeared]

My css code:

```css
#adminname {
-fx-background-color: white;
-fx-background-image: url("usericon.png");
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;   
-fx-background-size: 20 20;
-fx-background-position: left center;
-fx-background-color: #a9a9a9 , white , white;
-fx-background-insets: 0 -1 -1 -1, 0 0 0 0, 0 -1 3 -1;
 }

 #adminname:focused {
-fx-background-color: white;
-fx-background-image: url("usericon.png");
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;   
-fx-background-size: 25 25;
-fx-background-position: left center;
-fx-background-color: #a9a9a9 , white , white;
-fx-background-insets: 0 -1 -1 -1, 0 0 0 0, 0 -1 3 -1;
-fx-min-width: 170;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide your CSS code. In most cases, this can be done by adding the `text-indent` property. Like so: `text-indent: 20px;`

Comment: I will try it now and post my code if it doesn't work,thank you :)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Aziz `text-indent` is not a valid JavaFX CSS property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-fx-padding` ([see CSS properties for `Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)). Note however that the padding is not empty by default, so don't use 0 on the other values:

```
-fx-padding: 4 7 4 27;
```

The padding works the same way as in the [standard css model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions). IMHO that description is better than the one in the [javadoc for the `Region` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html). The important thing is the padding sets the distance to the border (i.e. the rounded rectangle around the `TextField`) but isn't applied for the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked :),but can you explain me about those parameters 4 7 4 27,am new to FX.

Comment: @user5904075 Added a link for css box model (specification), but maybe you should refer to a less formal resource, if this is the first time you hear about it: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp